# Wrapping a C++ interface in C

Tags: c++, c, pointers, visual-studio-2008, interface

I have a `C++` application which implemented as a `dll` and it is running succesfuly with `C++` applications.
Now I’m trying to wrap my `C++` interface in `C` to be able to use my app with `C` clients as well.

I’ve written one of the methods of my `C++` interface (`“Writer.hpp”`) that i want to call in `C`. In `C` i’ve written a `C_Writer.h` and `C_Writer.c` for wrapping.

`C_Writer.h` includes the pointer to `C++` type (structs) definitions and the method that i want to call in `C`.

In `C_Writer.c`, i’ve included `Writer.hpp` (C++ interface) and `C_Writer.h` and i’ve connected the `C` pointers to `C++` types with `C++` types, also declared the method.

Now what i’m trying to do is to call this `C` method in a simple `C` console application (`CInterfaceTest`) to test if it works.

But at the line `“dataTimeStamp -> timeStamp.date.Day = 10;”` it gives the error `“1>.\CInterfaceTest.cpp(22) : error C2027: use of undefined type ' Timestamp_Alias'”`.

Do you have an idea what i’m missing?

Here is the part of the code:

C++ interface

```
Writer.hpp
virtual Status write(DataBlock sampleData, TimeStamp dataTimestamp) = 0;
```

C interface

```
C_Writer.h
#ifndef __C_WRITER_H__
#define __C_WRITER_H__

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif

/*----------------------------------------------------*/

#if defined (WRITER_DLL_EXPORT)
    #define WRITER_DLL __declspec(dllexport)
#elif defined (WRITER_DLL_IMPORT)
    #define WRITER_DLL __declspec(dllimport)
#else 
    #define WRITER_DLL
#endif

//TYPEDEFS:
struct Status_Alias;
typedef struct Status_Alias* ptrToStatusType;
struct Timestamp_Alias;
typedef struct Timestamp_Alias* ptrToTimestampType;
struct DataBlock_Alias;
typedef struct DataBlock_Alias* ptrToDataBlockType;
//C-FUNCTIONS
I_WRITER_DLL extern
ptrToStatusType write_c (ptrToDataBlockType sampleData, ptrToTimestampType dataTimestamp);
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif //__C_WRITER_H__
```

Implementation File:

```
C_Writer.c

#include "Writer.hpp"
#include "C_Writer.h" 

struct Status_Alias
{
    Status status;
};

struct Timestamp_Alias
{
    Time_Stamp timeStamp;
};

struct DataBlock_Alias
{
    DataBlock sampleBlock;
};
ptrToStatusType write_c (ptrToDataBlockType sampleData, ptrToTimestampType dataTimestamp)
{
  Status_Alias* alias = new Status_Alias ();
  alias->status = GetWriterInterface()->write(sampleData->sampleBlock,dataTimestamp->timeStamp);

  return alias;
}
```

Simple console application to test c interface.

```
//testing C interface
// CInterfaceTest.cpp : main project file.

#include "C_Writer.h"

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ptrToStatusType statusCont;
    ptrToDataBlockType datablock;
    ptrToTimestampType dataTimeStamp; //10-10-2012 10:20:25

    dataTimeStamp -> timeStamp.date.Day = 10;
    dataTimeStamp -> timeStamp.date.Month = 10;
    dataTimeStamp -> timeStamp.date.Year = 2012;
    dataTimeStamp -> timeStamp.time.Hours = 10;
    dataTimeStamp -> timeStamp.time.Minutes = 20;
    dataTimeStamp -> timeStamp.time.Seconds = 25;

    statusCont = write_c(datablock, dataTimeStamp);

      return;
}
```

NOTE: I'm working with Visual Studio 2008 ide, in Win7 x64 machine.

Comment: This line -> `static void Main(string[] args)` <- does *not* look like C or C++!

Comment: Also, how could you be including a C++ header in a C file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't define your structures in `C_Writer.h` file. You cannot access to a structure members if they are not declared. Also you included C++ header into the C source file. You should compile your wrapper with your dll, not with a C project.

Actually, if you want to wrap C++ classes for C, there is no way to access its members directly. For example, in such purposes, you can use setters/getters declared as extern functions to access them:

```
// C_Writer.h
I_WRITER_DLL extern void setDateDay(ptrToTimestampType ptr, int value);
I_WRITER_DLL extern int getDateDay(prtToTimestampType ptr);
```

Implement them into `C_Writer.cpp` and compile with your dll. This is the easiest way I see.

Comment: I had the exactly same problem when worked on my C project which used a C++ library. I found this way as the most clear and easy.